# most strange bug found ever with a recursive program to calculate a determinant of a matrix

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-memory-allocation

Please anybody can find a bug on this code? I try to create a function to calculate a determinant of a matriz nXn. The program runs normally but a 'sobrenatural' thing happens. I declarate the variable 'ch' of type 'char' and I don't need it anymore. But if I remove this variable a execution error occurr. Why?

```
/*the function 'pot' calculate a integer pow of a integer*/
int determinante( int** matriz , int dimensao ){
    char cc;/*remove this variable and execute the code. On my PC a error occurr*/
    int cont = dimensao;
    int det = 0;
    int i, j, k, aux;
    int** matriz_aux;
    if( cont > 1 ){
        cont --;
        for( i = 0; i < dimensao; i++){
            matriz_aux = (int**) malloc( cont * sizeof(int*));
            if( matriz_aux == NULL ){
                printf("ERRO!\n");
                exit(-3);
            }
            for( j = 0; j < cont; j++){
                *(matriz_aux + j) = (int*) malloc( cont * sizeof(int));
                if(*(matriz_aux + j) == NULL){
                    printf("ERRO!\n");
                    exit(-4);
                }
            }
            for( j = 0; j < cont; j++){
                    for(k = 0, aux = 0; k < dimensao; k++){
                        printf("Aqui\n");
                        if( i != k ){
                            printf(" i = %d\n", i);

                            /*I forgive to add 'j' in '*(*(matriz + 1 + j) + k ). Now  it works but the bug stay here*/

                            *(*(matriz_aux + j) + aux) = *(*(matriz + 1 + j) + k);
                            aux++;
                        }
                    }
            }
            det += matriz[0][i]*pot( -1, i)*determinante(matriz_aux, cont);
        }
    }
    else {
        det += matriz[0][0];
    }

    for( i = 0; i < cont; i++){
        free( matriz_aux[i] );
    }
    free( matriz_aux );
    //printf(" determinant value = %d\n", det);
    return det;
}
```

Comment: Change the pointer syntax to array syntax. Instead of *(matriz_aux + j) and *(*(matriz_aux + j) + aux), use matrix_aux[j] and matriz_aux[j][aux]. Makes it much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

What's the error?  If removing that variable causes problems, you're probably overflowing the stack.  Try setting it to a value like 0xAB at the start of the function, and then print it out at the end.  If it changed, you've got a problem in your code.

Comment: it's impossible be an overflowing of stack. how one more variable can overflowing it?

Comment: With `cc` in place, you're possibly overflowing that single byte.  Without `cc`, you end up writing to the stack instead of the unused variable.  You could keep `cc` in place, and have the debugger break on a write to that byte to test that theory.

Answer (score 2):

```
*(matriz_aux + j) = (int*) malloc( cont * sizeof(int));
/*...*/
*(*(matriz_aux + j) + aux) = *(*(matriz + 1) + k);
```

`aux` can be equal to `cont`, which makes the second statement above a buffer overrun.  This is Undefined Behavior, so it might or might not crash.  Anything can cause a change.

Comment: In which case, for exemple, aux can be equal to cont? I can't see that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a major memory leak. You're allocating memory for the auxilliary matrix `dimension` times within the loop. But you're freeing it only once. Change your allocation logic to only do the allocation once.

Comment: is correct.  You should be allocating `matriz_aux` and the pointers inside of it just once, outside of the `for (i = 0...` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I foud the problem. Possibly with use of free in the end of the code. I'm trying free non-allocated memory. The correct code is:

```
int determinante( int** matriz , int dimensao ){
    int cont = dimensao;
    int det = 0;
    int i, j, k, aux;
    int** matriz_aux;
    if( cont > 1 ){
        cont --;
        for( i = 0; i < dimensao; i++){
            printf(" i inicial = %d\n", i);
            matriz_aux = (int**) malloc( cont * sizeof(int*));
            if( matriz_aux == NULL ){
                printf("ERRO!\n");
                exit(-3);
            }
            for( j = 0; j < cont; j++){
                *(matriz_aux + j) = (int*) malloc( cont * sizeof(int));
                if(*(matriz_aux + j) == NULL){
                    printf("ERRO!\n");
                    exit(-4);
                }
            }
            for( j = 0; j < cont; j++){
                    for(k = 0, aux = 0; k < dimensao; k++){
                        if( i != k ){
                            printf("valor de i = %d\n", i);
                            *(*(matriz_aux + j) + aux) = *(*(matriz + j + 1) + k);
                            aux++;
                        }
                    }
            }
            det += matriz[0][i]*pot( -1, i)*determinante(matriz_aux, cont);
        }
        /*Is here that shoud be free 'matriz_aux'*/
        for( i = 0; i < cont; i++){
            free( matriz_aux[i] );
        }
        free( matriz_aux );
    }
    else {
        det += matriz[0][0];
    }

    /*for( i = 0; i < cont; i++){
        free( matriz_aux[i] );
    }
    free( matriz_aux );*/
    return det;
}

/*here is the function 'pot'*/


int pot(int x , int y){
    int result;
    if( y == 0 ){//base case
       result = 1;
    }
    else if( y > 0 ){
        result =  x*pot( x , y-1 );//inductive step
    }
    else if( x == 0 ){
        printf("ERRO!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank's for the answers!